# Wordpress website down with error "redirected you too many times."

Tags: redirect, errors

I have a website that has been down for awhile with the redirect loop. I also cannot access wp-admin, gives me the same exact message. I was wondering if i could get this fixed asap since its a customers website. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** in the database or back-office ? Does it match with your `wp-config.php` **WP_HOME** and **WP_SITEURL**. If it still doesn't work you can deactivate all the plugins (rename the `wp-content/plugins/` folder) and reinstall them one at a time.

Source : [WPBeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-error-too-many-redirects-issue-in-wordpress/)

Comment: ...actually, the settings in wp-config.php override the settings in the wp-options table. I never put URLs in the wp-config.php file....but make sure that the two URL spots in the wp-options table are correct.